# Android File Stream

Tags: android

Can someone help me with my questions?

1. Can I read unicode content form a text file and display it on the console?
2. If the text is larger than a single page, how can read them to display page by page with some time out?

Comment: Please do not ask unrelated questions in the same post.  As you already have a response which attempts to answer both, it may be late to fix it this time, but please don't do that again.

Answer (score 0):

I try to mention some methods, to solve your problem. Isn't any of them is complete, but I think you'll be able to Google after them.

I would solve this problem in three parts...

> 1. Can I read unicode content form a text file?

Where do you want to store the file? Is it coming from the Internet? Or is it staticly inserted into the app, or modifiable by the user?

If the first one, I'd suggest you, to use the WebView class. It's a built-in View in Android, and displays an HTML file from the internet. See the docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).

If it's coming from the internet, but you'd like to implement the downloading, and displaying stuff, you should read about [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), and Java's FileReaders. The AsyncTask is a special built-in class, where you can create a method, that'll run in another thread, not in the UI thread, and create a method, that'll run in the UI thread after the previous one. It's important, 'cause you cannot create HTTP connections in the UI thread, but also cannot refresh the UI from any other thread. About reading from the internet, here's a small sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();
}
```

And some [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html).

If you want to read from the device, the main question is, do you want to edit the file on the device, also?

If not, I'd put the file into the assets folder. In the Android Studio it's at `src/main/assets/`, and after that you'll be able to open the file as a `BufferedReader` this way:

```
reader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("filename.txt")));
```

If you want to edit the file, you should save it in the `INTERNAL_STORAGE`. Here's the code to open a `BufferedReader`:

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(openFileInput("filename.txt")));
```

About the Internal Storage, you can read in the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal).

About how to read from a BufferedReader, you can see an example in the first code, or I can recommend the official [Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html).

> 2. And display it on the console?

Which console would you like to display on? On the IDE's console? In this case, you should use `Log.d("SomeTagThatTagsThisClass", "Message I'd Like To Display");`

Or you'd like to display the text on the device? In this case, you should create a create a `TextView` in the Activity, and set the text, something like this:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytextview);
tv.setText("Some string...");
```

> 3. If the text is larger than a single page, how can read them to display page by page with some time out?

If the text is too large, I'd use a `ScrollView`. It's a simple, scrollable view, automatically hides the overflow of the text, and you'll be able to scroll it.

If you prefer to display the text *page-by-page*, I'd use a `ViewPager`, and display the text on more `Fragment`s.

Comment: Starting the answer off with "I bet you've never written a program before" only furthers the issue that Stack Overflow is a hostile environment.  See rule #1 at the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior

Comment: you're totally right.