# My app keeps crashing on when I'm using AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm developing an app which downloads any image or pdf file in internal storage using a url. For this I'm using the AsyncTask class. The problem occurs as soon as I click the download button. My app crashes and when I check the internal storage of the emnulator, no file is saved. This problem is only occuring in the AsyncTask class. The rest of the class are giving no such issues.

```
class FileDownload extends AsyncTask<String, Void, File> {
    ProgressDialog p;

    public File downloadFile(String url) {
        File file = null;
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = new URL(url).openStream();
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return file;
    }

    public void saveImage(Context context, File file, String imageName) {
        FileOutputStream foStream;
        try {
            foStream = context.openFileOutput(imageName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            foStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("saveFile", "Oops! Something went wrong!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        p = new ProgressDialog(p.getContext());
        p.setMessage("Downloading. Please wait...");
        p.setIndeterminate(false);
        p.setCancelable(false);
        p.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected File doInBackground(String... strings) {
        return downloadFile(strings[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(File file) {
        super.onPostExecute(file);
        saveImage(p.getContext(), file, "file");
    }

}
```

Maybe I'm writing some line(s) of code(s) in the wrong place which is why my app is crashing, but I can't figure out where it is. Help please! :(

Comment: Any stack trace please?

Comment: Stack trace please

Comment: Your `File` instance in `downloadFile` is null. You are initialising it as `null` but it is never changed.

Comment: Oh, then what will be the parameters inside new File(); ?

Comment: Please take a look on this code sample to get a general understanding how to read data from the web stream and write to the file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409640/android-file-stream. Also please note ```AsyncTask``` is exist for ~15 years and officially deprecated since API 30, it is recommended to ```Use the standard java.util.concurrent or Kotlin concurrency utilities instead```